# Joomla wysiwyg keeps replacing certain sequences of numbers by asterisks on save

Tags: content, jce, tinymce

We have noticed that we are unable to save certain links in our articles if they contain a specific sequence of numbers. i.e. a link: `https://www.nature.com/articles/s41893-020-00622-1` will be changed to `https://www.nature.com/articles/s***********0622-1`

It doesn't matter if it's a website link, it also works with only the `41893-020-00622-1` sequence of numbers. It will be replaced with `***********0622-1`.

I've tried a new empty Joomla 3 installation and different wysiwyg editors (TinyMCE, JCE) but the problem is still there.

Could some of you please try to replicate the problem by saving for instance "s41893-020-00622-1" into a body of an article? A simple plain text is enough.
Any idea what could cause this? We have had this issue for a very long time, at least a couple of years.

Comment: While you wait, please take our [tour].

Comment: It is very odd to see such a unique substring affected.  Are you able to do a project-wide search (in your IDE, e.g. PHPStorm) to see if there is anything hard coded to target `41893-020-0`? Are no other strings affected in the same way? Alrernatively, you might search your project for `'*` which will be the starting portion of the replacement string.  Let us know if you find more clues.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this problem in Joomla 4 or a new install of Joomla 3.10 with just pasting your text into the article body. I would suspect a plugin.

Comment: Hi, I have now done more testing and you are right, a completely new Joomla 3.10 does not show this issue.

I started comparing the two sites' settings, plugins, components etc, all seem to be the same. 
I compared the binaries of files of each site. They are the same.
I even replaced the files of the new site with the files of the affected site and I am still unable to reproduce the problem on the new site. I even linked from one site to the other site's database and the problem is still the same. A useful thing I found is that the data is stored correctly in both databases.